# how to count Like and comment in getstream

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to create like/comment feature for feed in my app. Does getstream provide any api/method to find total number of comment/like on a post? Or do we have to save this info in our database and have to send only notification to getstream server?

If possible, any example

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently like/comments (i.e. related activities) are not supported natively on the Getstream.io API. Thus you would have to store this information locally in your own database (as you pointed out). A feature which would allow native support for this is on the roadmap. If it fits your specific usecase you could also use the aggregated feed format to aggregate on post id and verb to get the amount of likes on a certain post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when this feature is due to release.

Comment: is this feature avaiable in paid version of getstream?

Comment: @AnkeshKumar we don't currently have this on the roadmap as these are events you'd have to track manually. As Mattisk mentioned, you can use an aggregated feed to give you some totals of "like" activities for example. If you track a foreign_id on your activities (which we highly recommend) you could perhaps write a 'likes' quantity into the activity metadata and update the activity (updates require a foreign_id).

Comment: Would it be a viable solution to have an additional feed that handles just comments?

Like a "post" feed, and then a "post_comment" feed?